# Working with new instance of a class in Android

Tags: android

Totally new and starting out just working through the app tutorials. I wanted to run an algorithm to test out how it runs. I have it working all perfectly in java but am not sure how to create a class instance correctly in android.

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    myAlgorithm myAlg = new myAlgorithm();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            // Get the message from the intent
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

            // Create the text view
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTextSize(40);
            textView.setText(message);

            // Set the text view as the activity layout
            setContentView(textView);


        }
```

However as soon as run the program I get a force close. I take it this isn't the correct way to do it with Android?

TIA

Comment: Post the logcat and we will find out the reason.

Comment: the only thing i can see from the code you posted is that an exception might be getting thrown in the myAlgorithm constructor. nothing else would cause an exception. unless you have something in the calling activity that crashes in onStop or something like that

Comment: Yes I think your are correct toadzky. There some complex stuff in the algorithm and I think that Android isn't capable of running it.